# My ball doesn't move smoothly but with stutters. How can I achieve smoother movement?

Tags: processing

So this is processing project I have here https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/672559 does work OK but the ball and the paddles don't really go very smooth when it goes faster.  (you have to press the  button to show the code on this page)

After a couple of bounces the ball becomes a bit jittery and I would like to know how to avoid that or make the whole movement smoother.

This is the code for the ball without the colors.

```
   //ball variables
PVector ballVelocity = new PVector(0, 0); //velocity of ball
PVector ballPosition = new PVector(initial.x/2, initial.y/2); //position of ball

int maxPositions = 10; //the x positions
float radius = 10; //radius of ball

colour currentCol = new colour(255, 255, 255);

void placeBall() {
  ballBeforePosition = new PVector(ballPosition.x, ballPosition.y);
  ballPosition = new PVector(initial.x/2, initial.y/2);
  ballPosition.x *= scalar.x;
  ballPosition.y *= scalar.y;
  ballVelocity.y = (float)(Math.random()*(10*scalar.y))-(4*scalar.y);
  while (abs(ballVelocity.y)<1) ballVelocity.y = (float)(Math.random()*(10*scalar.y))-5;

  if (!leftScored && rightScored) {
    ballVelocity.x = 5 * scalar.x;
  } else if (leftScored && !rightScored) {
    ballVelocity.x = -5 * scalar.x;
  } else {
    if ((int)(Math.random()*2)==1) {
      ballVelocity.x = 5 * scalar.x;
    } else {
      ballVelocity.x = -5 * scalar.x;
    }
  }
}

void accelerateBall(float acceleration) {
  PVector newVelo = new PVector(ballVelocity.x * acceleration, ballVelocity.y * acceleration); //velocity of ball
  ballVelocity = new PVector(newVelo.x, newVelo.y);
  if (abs(ballVelocity.x)>(player1.dim().x+maxEndSpeed)) {
    ballVelocity.x = sign(ballVelocity.x)*(player1.dim().x+maxEndSpeed);
    return;
  }
}


void decelerateBall(float deceleration){
  PVector newVelo = new PVector(ballVelocity.x / deceleration, ballVelocity.y / deceleration); //velocity of ball
  ballVelocity = new PVector(newVelo.x, newVelo.y);
  if (abs(ballVelocity.x)< 5 * scalar.x) {
    ballVelocity.x = sign(ballVelocity.x)*(5 * scalar.x);
    return;
  }
}
void runBallCollision(PVector pot, paddle p) {
  if (collides(pot, p)) {
    hitcount++;
    firstcollision++;

    if (firstcollision ==3) {
      accelerateBall(1.5);
    }

    if ((p==player1&&pot.x > p.pos().x)||(p==player2&&pot.x < p.pos().x)) {
      PVector tempVel = new PVector(ballPosition.x - p.pos().x, (ballPosition.y - p.pos().y)/5);
      tempVel.normalize();
      tempVel.mult(ballVelocity.mag());
      ballVelocity = tempVel;
    } else if (!sameSign(p.moveAmount(), ballVelocity.y)&&p.moveAmount()!=0) {
      //p.speedBurst();
      ballVelocity.x *= -1;
      ballVelocity.y = abs(ballVelocity.y)*sign(p.moveAmount())+(p.moveAmount());
      if (p==player1) {
        ballPosition.x = p.pos().x + (p.dim().x) + radius;
      }
      if (p==player2) {
        ballPosition.x = p.pos().x - (p.dim().x) - radius;
      }
    }

    if (firstcollision<3 || firstcollision > 3 ) {
      accelerateBall(1.05);
    }

    projected = false;
  }
}

void moveBall() {
  PVector potPos = PVector.add(ballPosition, ballVelocity);

  runBallCollision(potPos, player1);
  runBallCollision(potPos, player2);

  if (potPos.y - radius <= 0+cornerwidth) {
    ballVelocity.y *= -1;
  } else if (potPos.y + radius >= height-cornerwidth) {
    ballVelocity.y *= -1;
  }

  ballPosition.add(ballVelocity);


  //GOAL
  if (ballPosition.x<0+cornerwidth) {
    rightScored = true;
    leftScored = false;
    reset(player2, true);
  } else if (ballPosition.x>width-cornerwidth) {
    rightScored = false;
    leftScored = true;
    reset(player1, true);
  }
}

void displayBall() {
  pushMatrix();
  PVector newPosi = ballBeforePosition;
  translate(ballPosition.x, ballPosition.y);
  fill(currentCol.R(), currentCol.G(), currentCol.B());
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 0, radius*2, radius*2);
  popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's quite a lot of code but i can search the main part for the ball...

Comment: How should one answer the question without any code?

Comment: The code is in the sketch here: https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/672559

Comment: What do I've to do to see the code? Do I need to create an account and to login?

Comment: no - just click this </> sign in the middle ( to play the game press 1 for first player, then you can move the paddle up and down with w and s respectively)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Any news?

Comment: it is not jittery when i see it. it is a bit jittery technically but that is an illusion because of how fast it is moving. it is not really a problem.